# Mongo Db optimized query

Tags: mongodb, query-optimization

In my use case I am having more than 3000 variable ids which I have assigned to other collection as foreign key in mongo db. In the other collection, for each foreign key there are more number of document which contains the one of the field in list type. I need to query to retrieve the distinct foreign key from the 3000, by satisfying the condition that at least one of the document of each foreign key  list size to greater than 0. i am currently using the below queries as sample.

**`db.values.distinct('variable',{variable:{$in:variableIds}, $nor:[{source: {$exists: false}},{source: {$size: 0}}]})`**

where variable is the foreign key of the "values" collection as below.
`variableIds` is the list of unique ids as primary keys from variable collection.

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("546db048e4b0c0187ab9eefd"),
"dateNum" : 41274,
"source" : [
    {
        "value" : 625,
        "formatCode" : "General"
    }
],
 "variable"  : ObjectId("546db048e4b0c0187ab9eefc")
}
```

But due to 3000 ids in `$in` condition the query seems to be large and taking more time to execute is there another way to optimize the query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One optimization is to add the `variable` field to the `index`.

Just to demonstrate its effect. Let values be a collection having just three documents, two of which match the `variable` we are looking for.

Sample data:

```
db.values.insert([{
"_id" : 1,
"dateNum" : 41274,
"source" : [
    {
        "value" : 625,
        "formatCode" : "General"
    }
],
 "variable"  : 1
},
{
"_id" : 2,
"dateNum" : 41274,
"source" : [
    {
        "value" : 625,
        "formatCode" : "General"
    }
],
 "variable"  : 1
},
{
"_id" : 3,
"dateNum" : 41274,
"source" : [
    {
        "value" : 625,
        "formatCode" : "General"
    }
],
 "variable"  : 2
}
])
```

Say we run the query over this collection without the index on the variable field.

```
db.runCommand({ distinct: 'sample',
                key:'variable',
                query:{variable:{$in:[1]}, 
                       $nor:[{source: {$exists: false}},{source: {$size: 0}}]}
              })
```

We get the below output. On examining the output we find that the value of the total number of documents scanned in the collection - `nscannedObjects` is `3`. So this has resulted in a full collection scan.

```
{
        "values" : [
                1
        ],
        "stats" : {
                "n" : 2,
                "nscanned" : 3,
                "nscannedObjects" : 3,
                "timems" : 0,
                "cursor" : "BasicCursor"
        },
        "ok" : 1
}
```

Now we add an index on the `variable` field.

```
db.sample.ensureIndex({"variable":1})
```

And on running the command we get the below output which states that the total documents scanned is only `2`. And those are the documents that had the exact `variable` as in the search query.

```
{
        "values" : [
                1
        ],
        "stats" : {
                "n" : 2,
                "nscanned" : 2,
                "nscannedObjects" : 2,
                "timems" : 59,
                "cursor" : "BtreeCursor variable_1"
        },
        "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: i have added the index also shows the same result and i also  searching that passing more than 3000 items in $in will cause any performance issue and also is there any other alternate query other than using distinct

Comment: Index the fields `variable` and `source.value`. And then try the below query: db.sample.distinct('variable',{variable:{$in:[1]}, "source.value":{$exists:true}})